# How do I fetch NSArray elements with nth count?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

If there is an NSArray with nth count, I need to fetch first 3 element and then next 3 element so on.

```
example:- [A,B,C,D,E,F,G]  
result1:- [A,B,C]  
result2:- [D,E,F]  
result3:- [G]
```

I have array of nth element for which I wanted to fetch each 3 element from beginning of the array till nth element.

Tried code,

```
 myArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"k",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Z",nil‌​]; 
 NSArray *getData=[myArr subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, MIN(3, myArr.count))]; 
 i=i+3;
```

Comment: You tried anything?.

Comment: myArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"k",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Z",nil];  NSArray *getData=[myArr subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, MIN(3, myArr.count))];   i=i+3;

Comment: yes i have  tried above code but it is ok with the set of 3 element like 3 6 9  etc but when we have suppose 7 element then app will crash.

Comment: @techno Please update your question with your efforts. Do not post your code in comments.

Comment: Yeah, you should post code in question instead of comment!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
NSArray *a = @[ @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7 ];

int start = 0;
int slice_size = 3;
while (start < a.count) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(start, slice_size);
        if (range.location + range.length >= a.count) {
                range.length = a.count - range.location;
        }

        NSArray *slice = [a subarrayWithRange:range];

        NSLog(@"slice: %@", slice);

        start += slice_size;
}
```